# Can I ask a question even if I know the answer?

Tags: discussion, support

To get answers from other users. Someone else may have a better answer. So, can I ask a question even though I know the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can and AFAIK there's nothing which doesn't allow you to do this, as you might ask a question and do some research and find the appropriate answer for your issue yourself, even if somebody else gave an answer or before anybody could answer your question. Both happened to me in the SE/SO network. There's even a badge for that https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/badges/14/self-learner.

And you may find a direct answer in our [help-center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Note maybe your question would have been asked before. And maybe your answer could be wrong or others have a better or more elaborated answer or a more helpful answer ...